# Alter the "From" address contact form

Tags: 8, emails

I'm trying to alter the email and change the default "From" address to a different email address.

```
function mymodule_mail_alter(&$message){
   $message['from'] = 'myemail@gmail.com';
}
```

When I test send a test email through my site Contact Form.  The email "From" address is still using the default site email not the one I altered in my module.

Is there another way to make this work?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue myself. I got it to work in the following way:

```
function mymodule_mail_alter(&$message){

  $message['from'] = "do-no-reply@example.com";
  $message['headers']['From'] = 'Name TO SHOW <do-no-reply@example.com>';
  $message['headers']['Sender'] = $message['headers']['Return-Path'] = $message['from'];
}
```

However, like you,  I thought adding `$message['from'] = 'myemail@gmail.com';` is the way to go and I think it should -Perhaps other folks can chime in and let us know if this is a bug?

In any case, it seems drupal does more processing and checks to verify the `from` email address and if it [does not pass all the checks it sets it to the sitemail, or the mail](https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/8.8.x/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Mail/MailManager.php#L255) library just use the other headers. Note I think this behavior may differ based on which mail library you are using. In my case, and I presume in yours, its [PhpMail.php](https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/8.8.x/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Mail/Plugin/Mail/PhpMail.php).

The solution above worked but I am not sure if it's the most appropriate or if it would work for others who are using different mail managers..

Comment: `$message['headers']` is what gets used by default (using the default PhpMail plugin) for all the mail headers, including the 'From' header. `$message['from']` is ignored by default. This is as designed. It *is* possible that a different mail plugin might not do the same thing, but it's safest to just assume all plugins do the same thing as the default plugin.